# Interval of convergence for a power series with $x^{2n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

By definition, the radius of convergence (which is equivalent to the interval) is:

$$R:=\frac{1}{\varlimsup_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}}$$

Where $\varlimsup_{n\rightarrow+\infty}$ is the limit superior for a given power series $\Sigma a_n x^n$

How do I find the radius of convergence for a series of the form $\Sigma a_n x^{2n}$? What about $\Sigma a_n x^{2n+1}$?

As an example, I'm checking the Taylor Series of $\frac{1}{x^2+3}$ which is $\Sigma_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{2n}}{3^{n+1}}.(-1)^n$.
If I just ignore the fact that I'm dealing with $x^2$ instead of $x$ then $R=3$ while it should be $\sqrt3$

Comment: Just a note: A more common notation is $\limsup$ (`\limsup`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. Let $y=x^2$ and see what the series now looks like.

Or, since Cauchy-Hadamard theorem works based on Cauchy root test (which I suppose you know), for $x^{2n},x^{2n+1}$ or whatever, as long as the exponent  is $dn+k$, you can just do it in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Observe that a series of the form $\sum \limits_{n = 0}^\infty a_n x^{2n}$ is equal to $\sum \limits_{n = 0}^\infty b_n x^n$ where $b_n = \begin{cases} a_{\frac{n}{2}} & \text{if $n$ is even} \\ 0 &\text{else}\end{cases}$.